# Is $\sin(x)$ in $\mathcal{O}(1)$?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Well I was learning about big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation and I wondered whether $\sin(x)$ is in $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

A function $f(x)$ is in $\mathcal{O}(g(x))$ if $f(x)≤C·g(x)$ for all $x>k$ where $C$ and $k$ are an arbitrary constants. Since $\sin(x)$ has a fixed amplitude, there will always be constant values which we can choose such that $\sin(x)<C$.

So I think that $\sin(x)$ is $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

However, I could not find much information about this on the Internet and Chat GPT says I am wrong.

Comment: 1. You are right.  2. ChatGPT is a language model, designed to produce text that looks intelligible; essentially, it is a (much) more sophisticated version of 10,000 monkeys at 10,000 typewriters.  Its purpose is not to say true things, and you should never expect anything it tells you to be true.  (3) Please learn basic LaTeX/MathJax syntax:  enclose all math symbols (C, k, ...) in math mode, use \sin, \leq, \cdot, etc.

Comment: Since $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$, $|\sin x| \leq 1$, that is $\sin x$ is $O(1)$ as $x \to +\infty$ (sometimes when using Big O Notation writers will restrict attention to functions that are everywhere positive). In my experience ChatGPT often yields incorrect (but confident-sounding) answers to mathematical questions---you should not rely on its answers.

Comment: You're correct in your argumentation of $\sin x$ being $O(1)$. You're  wrong in expecting chatgpt to give a correct answer for a mathematical question.

Comment: ChatGPT indeed yields incorrect (but confident-sounding) answers. Worse, it also pretends to acknowledge and correct its errors (without actually correcting anything) https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FuPG9diX0AEHbhu?format=png

Comment: Chat GPT is a great example that something can have a gigantic degree of uselesness and nevertheless receive gigantic fame. One of the main problems of the human community !